# how to import contacts from phone to gmail account

Tags: java, android, export-to-csv

my application requires to import all my phone contactas to the gmail account registered with google market. The user should be able to export all contacts or just selected contacts to his/her gmail account. Can this even be done? I read that you can only do that when you add a new contact wish is quite annoying. Can i automatize that process? I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading abou the Contacts API:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

Comment: so i looked at that. It doesn't say how to export contacts to gmail. It only shows how to retrieve and manage contacts. Is there an API to export contacts to a gmail account? Maybe a web service? Thanks for the answer though.